# javascript switch statement jumps back in condition

Tags: javascript, recursion, switch-statement

I have simple array [3,7,9] where I try to search certain values recursively. If the value to be searched doesn't exist, it will be added to array, otherwise not. I'm using switch case structure but facing severe problems.

First searching value 2. Everything is fine until return of the function. For some reason code jumps back to break; -line in "case a:" Then sets itemFound to 'undefined'. Why this jump happens?

Searching value 5 jumps back to break; in "case b:" and again itemFound gets value "undefined".

With other values there are even more jumps.

I do expect the code to do one switch-case only and exit from conditional.

```
myArr = [3, 7, 9];

window.onload = init;

function init() {

    searchItem(myArr, 2);
    searchItem(myArr, 5);
    searchItem(myArr, 8);
    searchItem(myArr, 10);
    searchItem(myArr, 7);

    var arrLength = myArr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        console.log('index ' + i + ' ' + myArr[i]);
        // alert(myArr);
    }
}

function searchItem(array, itemToSearch) {
    var itemFound;
    var itemArray = array.slice(0);
    var arrLen = itemArray.length;
    var midPointIndex = Math.round(itemArray.length / 2) - 1;
    var midPointVal = itemArray[midPointIndex];

    switch (true) {

        //case a:
        case midPointVal < itemToSearch:
            if (arrLen > 1) {
                itemArray.splice(0, midPointIndex + 1);
                searchItem(itemArray, itemToSearch);
            } else {
                itemFound = false;
            }
            break;

        //case b:
        case midPointVal > itemToSearch:
            if (arrLen > 1) {
                itemArray.splice(midPointIndex, arrLen - midPointIndex);
                searchItem(itemArray, itemToSearch);
            } else {
                itemFound = false;
            }
            break;

        //case c:
        case midPointVal === itemToSearch:
            itemFound = true;
            break;
    }

    if (itemFound === false) {
        myArr.push(itemToSearch);
        myArr.sort();
        //arraySort(myArr);
    }


    console.log('Value ' + itemToSearch + ' found' + ': ' + itemFound);

    return itemFound;
}
```

Comment: @Andy: Obviously he expects the array to be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some reason code jumps back to break; -line in "case a:" Then sets itemFound to 'undefined'. Why this jump happens?

Because `return` jumps back one level on the call stack. You're not experiencing a jump inside the function, but a jump from the recursive invocation to where it was called - and where `itemFound` is still undefined.

> I try to search certain values recursively. If the value to be searched doesn't exist, it will be added to array, otherwise not.

That `myArr.push(itemToSearch);` does add the item to a completely different array - luckily the one you did initially pass in, but it's still a bad practise. Instead, it would be much more efficient if you just added it at the expected position in the `itemArray` - you even know already at what position it needs to be inserted, so no need to `.sort()` afterwards.

However, your recursive implementation does copy (slice) and modify (splice) the array, which will make it impossible to add it simply to the current array. Instead, leave the  array intact and use two variables/parameters `leftIndex` and `rightIndex` between which to search.